# Ubuntu/GlusterFS: Unable to create thinly provisioned volume from previously created pool using lvcreate

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, glusterfs, thinpool

I'm testing out glusterfs, and was following [this guide on creating setting up volumes](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Setting%20Up%20Volumes/). I ran into an error when trying to create a thinly provisioned volume. This is the section

> Create a thinly provisioned volume from the previously created pool using  the lvcreate command:
>
> > *For example:*
> >
> > `lvcreate -V 1G -T gfs_vg/gfs_pool -n gfs_lv`
>
> *It is recommended that only one LV should be created in a thin pool.*

This is the error I encountered:

```
/usr/sbin/thin_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
Check of pool gfs_vg/gfs_pool failed (status:2). Manual repair required!
Aborting. Failed to locally activate thin pool gfs_vg/gfs_pool.
```

Googling the issue. I tried to repair it via `lvconvert`, and it doesn't seem to work

```
root@DSI:/home/main# lvconvert --repair gfs_vg/gfs_pool
/usr/sbin/thin_repair: execvp failed: No such file or directory
Repair of thin metadata volume of thin pool gfs_vg/gfs_pool failed (status:2). Manual repair required!
```

Does anyone know what's the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Both errors are due to missing binaries. You're missing `/usr/sbin/thin_check` and `/usr/sbin/thin_repair`, which are tools that come with the `thin-provisioning-tools` package. The following should fix it:

```
apt-get -y install thin-provisioning-tools
```